# Setting permissions for published resource calendars not working

Tags: office-365, office-web-apps, exchange-online

I want to publish resource calendars to a public URL to allow anonymous users to view only the meeting availability, but it is showing the full details.

Here are my external sharing settings:
[image]

I created a new resource calendar and attempted to publish it with these commands:

```
$CalName = 'mynewroom:\calendar'Set-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity $CalName -PublishEnabled $trueGet-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity $CalNameSet-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity $CalName -DetailLevel LimitedDetails#Set-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity $CalName -DetailLevel FullSet-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity $CalName -PublishDateRangeTo OneYearSet-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity $CalName -PublishDateRangeFrom OneYear
```

I get this error:

```
The policy doesn't allow anonymous sharing with Limited Details.   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-MailboxCalendarFolder], NotAllowedPublishingByPol  cyException   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [<server GUID>,Time  tamp=7/1/2016 6:20:20 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-NotAllowedPublishingByPolicyException] BD7685768,M icrosoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.SetMailboxCalendarFolder   + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```